# Can I use CGI module to read and extract information from an uploaded FormData object file in python?

Tags: python

Can I use CGI module to read and extract information from an uploaded FormData object file in python?
The file is being uploaded on the server from the front end and I'd like to read the file and extract data from it.
So how do I go about it?

Comment: What web framework are you using? If any, it likely gives access to uploads. If not, consider at least web.py :)

Comment: I'm using HTML and angularJS at the front end to send a file to the backend which is in python. I now want to read the file. Will CGI work for that? @9000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [minimal recipe using web.py](http://webpy.org/cookbook/fileupload). Remove debug output, write to a file, otherwise update to taste. E.g. you might want authentication at this endpoint.

It's a `pip install web.py` away.